# Android Job Scheduler Job does not execute after app is closed

Tags: java, android, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, background-task

My Job executes perfectly if the app is open but if i close the app the jobservice is never executed. I have followed the tutorial here; [Job Scheduler - Code In Flow](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/jobscheduler) and it just does not run (or maybe it runs and we do not know it runs?). I have put in notifications and Log.d methods with in my methods so i can see if the job runs and while the app is open the log msgs and notifications push through as expected.

Any help would be appreciated . Thank you

**UPDATE 2**
  ===============
 I have discovered, since the job runs while the app is open, if i close the app the job gets cancelled without the `onStopJob` being called. theoretically if i am not wrong job scheduler should continue the job irrespective of the app running or not.
the Log.d msgs looks like this

```
D/global_PEA: Job Scheduled //Schedule Job Button Pressed
D/global_PEA: Job Started //ExJobService runs
D/global_PEA: run: 0
D/global_PEA: run: 1
D/global_PEA: run: 2
D/global_PEA: run: 3
D/global_PEA: run: 4
// App closed and the output and notifications stop
// in theory it should continue till 9
```

=======

**UPDATE**
  ===============
 Here is the adb shell dump of my app. it looks like its scheduled?
[image: adb_shellDump]

I cant get any notification or Log.d msgs when i force run the job from adb like so
`adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.raaif.pea 902`

which leads me to think that maybe the job does infact run but nothing is shown to the user about it like the notification. Is there any way it could notify the application, even if its openning the app when the job is done?

==============

here are my code files

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;

    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        btn1 = root.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn2= root.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scheduleJob();
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelJob();
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

    public void scheduleJob(){
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(mContext, ExJobService.class);
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID_1, componentName)
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)
                .build();

        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) mContext.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultcode = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if(resultcode==JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS){
            Log.d(globals.appTag,"Job Scheduled");
        }else{
            Log.d(globals.appTag,"Job Scheduling failed");
        }
    }

    public void cancelJob(){
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler)getContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        scheduler.cancel(JOB_ID_1);
        Log.d(globals.appTag,"Job cancelled");
    }
}
```

And here is my JobService class

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import static com.raaif.pea.Constants.CHANNEL_ID_NOTIFICATION_HIGH;
import static com.raaif.pea.Constants.HIGH_NOTIF_ID;

public class ExJobService extends JobService {
    private Globals globals = Globals.getInstance();
    private boolean jobcancelled = false;
    private boolean reschedulestatus = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(globals.appTag, "Job Started");
        //output low notification
        notify("Scheduled JobService", "Starting Background Work");
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    if (jobcancelled) return;
                    Log.d(globals.appTag, "run: " + i);
                    ExJobService.this.notify("Thread Iterator",
                            String.format("Iteration Count: %d", i));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.d(globals.appTag, "Job Finished");
                ExJobService.this.notify("Scheduled JobService", "Background Work Finished");
                jobFinished(params, reschedulestatus);
                Log.d(globals.appTag, "Job Service Params returned with " + reschedulestatus);
                ExJobService.this.notify("Scheduled JobService", "Job Params returned");
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(globals.appTag, "Job Cancelled before completion");
        jobcancelled = true;
        notify("OnStopJob", "Job Cancelled");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return Service.START_STICKY;
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void notify(String title, String content) {
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ExJobService.this, CHANNEL_ID_NOTIFICATION_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_memory_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                .build();
        notificationManager.notify(HIGH_NOTIF_ID, notification);
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.raaif.pea">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <!-- SERVICES -->
       <service android:name=".ExJobService"
           android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: your code looks fine, can you check if job is actually scheduled by executing this command over adb `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I see here is a problem but i don't know how do you handle it?! look at this:

```
public class ExJobService extends JobService {
    ...
    private boolean reschedulestatus = false;

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        ....
        doBackgroundWork(params);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                ....
                jobFinished(params, reschedulestatus);
                ....
        }).start();
    }
}
```

You are passing `false` to `jobFinished` method that unintentionally you do not reschedule the job.

Comment: Just to confirm, I just rebuilt the code with ```jobFinished(params, true);``` with no luck..I changed it to false in an attempt to make it work. initially i had it on true. I just forgot to switch it back to true

Comment: @XcOder does it schedule even ? does adb show it's sdheduled ?

Comment: i have attached adb jobscheduler dump of the app. im assuming it shows my app there because it is scheduled? im not too sure how to read the adb dump

Comment: @XcOder there is 2 condition u must find them.1- it is scheduled but not works  2-it is not scheduled but works. which of them?

Answer (score 0):

When doing stuff periodically in the background — JobScheduler, WorkManager, AlarmManager etc. — you have to take into account that your process might not be around when it is time for you to do your work. Android will fork a process for you, but it is "starting from scratch". Anything that your UI might have set up in memory, such as a database, would have been for some prior process and might not be set up in the new process.

Comment: so is there anyway i can push a notification after the job is done without possibly opening/launching the app?